# JSP internal server error calling a java method in an external java class

Tags: java, jsp

I am fairly new to using JSP but all I want to do at the minute is call a simple method from a JSP scriptlet. There are questions similar to this on this forum already, but any solution to those problems always seemed to be related to a simple typo, however as far as I can see, there is no typo in my code but I could be wrong.

Here is my JSP file (ShowBookings.jsp)-

[image: JSP File Image]

This is the Controller class that I am attempting to call.

[image: Controller.java Image]

This is the HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error I get when I try to run the web page.

[image: Internal Server Error Image]

I used images instead of code snippets to give a better idea of exactly what I am seeing. When I type in "controller.;" in the jsp file, the methods appear in the intellisense including the sayHello() method, so it does seem to be visible from the jsp file but it is still throwing an error. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code seems to be ok. Can you try doing a build and see if it works

Comment: what's your import for `Controller`?

Comment: @LearningPhase Thank you very much for the reply. Ya I built the project alright but now I seem to be getting a different error on the line where I am importing the Controller class. Saying "Only a type can be imported. ie.gmit.sw.dsConsumer.Controller resolves to a package". This error came without changing any of the code.

Comment: @user7294900 thanks for the reply but I'm not too sure what you mean by that question. Do you mean where is the Controller class that I am importing or what is the syntax for importing that Controller class?

Comment: import line inside JSP for Controller class

Comment: This is the import line - <%@page import="ie.gmit.sw.dsConsumer.Controller"%>